# I'm getting "cannot find symbol method setMargins(int, int, int, int)" when I try to set the Margins of EditText

Tags: android, margins

I'm trying to set the margins of multiple EditText widgets using setMargins(), but I'm getting:

> Error: cannot find symbol method setMarings(int, int, int, int).

Any ideas?
This is the xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="384dp"
    android:layout_height="589dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</ScrollView>
```

And this is that part of my code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams;


    LinearLayout linearLayout = LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    //noc is users' input
    for (int i = 1; i<=noc; i++) {

        EditText eText = new EditText(this);
        eText.setId(i);
        eText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //For example:
        eText.setMargins(24,0,24,0);
        linearLayout.addView(eText);
    }
```

Everything works fine if I just forget about the margins, but It would be better if I could set those.

Comment: **homework to developing coding skills:** Check the base hypothesis/assumption and *find* the documentation that says this method is allowed: what is the signature of said method, if it exists? (ie. code can't just "make up" an API; if it exists in can be used with the appropriate version/references, otherwise it does not exist, possibly by being called by having a *different signature*, a *different name*, or by being defined on a *different type*..)

Comment: I've added an answer

Comment: I assume the error message with `setMarings` (as opposed to `setMargins`) is just a typo in the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Root cause:** Your code to set margins is not correct.

**Solution:** Change your code

From

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
//noc is users' input
for (int i = 1; i<=noc; i++) {

    EditText eText = new EditText(this);
    eText.setId(i);
    eText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //For example:
    eText.setMargins(24,0,24,0);
    linearLayout.addView(eText);
}
```

To

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
//noc is users' input
for (int i = 1; i <= noc; i++) {
    EditText eText = new EditText(this);
    eText.setId(i);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(24, 0, 24, 0);
    eText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    linearLayout.addView(eText);
}
```

Comment: It wasn't me who down voted your answer, I'm just checking it, give me a couple of hours and I'll give you some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the method `setMargins` in the LayoutParams instance not in the View one.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

for (int i = 1; i<=noc; i++) {
    EditText eText = new EditText(this);
    eText.setId(i);

   LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   params.setMargins(24, 0, 24, 0);
   eText.setLayoutParams(params);
   linearLayout.addView(eText);
}
```

Comment: I tried it like that but it's still saying _cannot find symbol method setMargins()_

Answer (score 0):

When you set margins in XML, it looks like this:

```
android:layout_margin="16dp"
```

Any attribute that is prefixed with `layout_` will actually be an attribute of that view's `LayoutParams` object. This makes sense: the job of `LayoutParams` is to communicate with the parent view about how the child wants to be laid out, and margins are part of that process.

The `setMargins()` method is part of the [`ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) class. Most standard `ViewGroup`s use this (like `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, etc). So you could do something like this:

```
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) eText.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargin(16, 16, 16, 16);
eText.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Make sure to call `setLayoutParams()` when you're done setting the margins, or else your updates won't take effect.

Comment: It does compile now, but the activity is unable to start, it says that I'm trying to invoke _virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.setMargins(int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference_